# Logrotate: "log does not need rotating" why?

Tags: logrotate

I have the following new logrotate configuration:

```
/var/log/nexus/nexus.log {
    rotate 7
    missingok
    compress
    delaycompress
    copytruncate
    daily
}
```

When I run `logrotate -d nexus`, I get the following:

```
reading config file nexus
reading config info for /var/log/nexus/nexus.log

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/nexus/nexus.log  after 1 days (7 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/nexus/nexus.log
  log does not need rotating
```

My /var/log/nexus/ folder contains the following:

```
nexus.log
oldlogs.tar.gz
```

Why isn't LogRotate rotating the nexus.log file? What I was expecting was that the nexus.log file would have been truncated and a new file, something like nexus.log-201106241000, would have been created.

Comment: Also, remember, when you use the -d option, IT DOES NOT ROTATE LOGS. It shows you what it WOULD do it run without the option, like a game plan. Caused me some serious headaches when I thought I could see them rotating, and then they were still there.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Most likely, the log file is less than a day old and/or has been rotated within the last day and logrotate remembers the history.

If you add `-f` it'll force a rotation if you really want to (although not 100% sure how that interacts with `-d`).

You can look at the history, location depends on your distribution, but might be `/var/lib/logrotate/status`.  That file shows when logs were last rotated.

Comment: In FreeBSD it's /var/run/logrotate.status

Comment: Also check for possible use of the -s argument in the invocation for status file location

Comment: `-d` + `-f` makes logrotate report "needs rotating" for all files, even the ones that don't match

Comment: To add to this, editing the date in the status file to be older than the rotation policy is enough to convince `logrotate` it needs to rotate the log when it runs again.

Comment: On CentOS, I modified /var/lib/logrotate.status to get logrotate working.  As indicated by EightBitTony, the daily logrotate will  remembers the history.    Unless the file is in the history already with a date in the past, logrotate won't rotate the file.

Answer (score 76):

The first time you run logrotate with a new log configuration it doesn't know when the last log rotation occurred, so it just writes a status line in `/var/lib/logrotate/status` to the effect that it was run today.

When it subsequently runs the following day, it sees that the log is a day old and rotates it as expected.  If you don't want to wait, edit logrotate's status file and goose the status date for your log back to the previous day.

When you run logrotate manually, it will work as expected

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes even if you run logrotate manually, this won't work if you do it the same day and have `dateext` where default value doesn't include senconds (e.g. `-%Y%m%d`). Not even if you modify logrotate's status file or when using size directive (e.g. `size 200M`). At least on CentOS 6, logrotate will fail to rotate your log file because it already exists.

To solve this, you need to use `dateformat` instead of `dateext`, with a value like: `%Y%m%d%s`.

See `man logrotate` for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Beware that by running

```
logrotate -vdf /etc/logrotate.conf
```

the event although only simulated will be logged to `/var/lib/logrotate.status`
and subsequent logrotate runs will reply with the mentioned

```
log does not need rotating
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce that on Ubuntu (16.04 and 17.04). If "/var/lib/logrotate.status" is used, you must be used another distro. Ubuntu logs to "/var/lib/logrotate/status".

Comment: @Philipp Claßen: You are right this (status file placed at `/var/lib/logrotate.status`) has been observed while debugging configuration of Logrotate 3.10 on Alpine linux 3.5 within a docker container.

But there is no Ubuntu flag in the question definition, is it?

Comment: Yes, it's alright. I would just mention it because Ubuntu is so popular. I assume many people read this question because they want to fix their server, which today often runs with Ubuntu.

Comment: OK, that's right. To be complete I can add that the locationo of the status file at Centos 7 distro is at `/var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status`